# What are these strange emoji's/characters and why do I keep seeing them?

Tags: safe-browsing-filter

To tell the story; I got in to a battle of words on Twitter some months ago. I had since blocked them. However recently as a few day ago I saw them pop up again in a comment on a Tweet I was reading. I did not screenshot the actual tweet but I saw this as the first comment on a friends status on Facebook at the top of my newsfeed. I'm concerned this could be some kind of security related thing.

What does this mean and if its something unsafe what can I do about it?

[edit] I'm sorry I forgot about the facebook profile pics. Give me just a minute to remove them and reupload the picture.
[edit2] Done.
[image: What is this in the orange box]

Comment: They're probably just symbols/icons your system does not support, so they show up as boxes.

Comment: likely symbols from other languages - people combine them with emoji to create compound images

Comment: UTF-8 characters your web browser cannot display because you don't have a font installed that has that particular codepoint. Bet it would show if you had access to a Linux distrubution. Looks to be 03eb => ϫ or 3eb0-3ebf which you can view in Character Map if you use the MingLiU font.